# Tooling API / Packaging

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-communities

I am quite a beginner both as developer and in Salesforce ecosystem.

For reporting I am developing a package using tooling API to get LayoutFullName.

So far using documentation found in the web, I have succeed using two methods:

- Stocking information (username, password, client secret, etc..) in custom labels, and then using it in Apex Code. But I suspect that it is not the way to go for reasons of security and also user comfort.
- Using Name Credentials. But for that, I have to specify a endpoint (the org user).

Is there a way to configure this endpoint dynamically?